# How to fetch latest 10 records from mysql database using nodejs?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I want to know if there is any way to fetch latest 10 records from mysql database using nodejs.

I found this: [Node.js MySQL Limit](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_limit.asp) . But it only shows the way to fetch first records and the records between two indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `ORDER BY DESC`, you can get the latest rows and use the limit for N numbers

```
  var mysql = require('mysql');
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
      host: "localhost",
      user: "yourusername",
      password: "yourpassword",
      database: "mydb"
    });
    
    con.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var sql = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ";
      con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer, try this query.....

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
) sub ORDER BY id ASC
```